Blazor submit button
I am starting with Blazor and I want add data to DB. But after filling InputTexts submit button not working (Not going to InsertUser).
Here is my code:
@page "/Users"
@using DataAccessLibrary
@using DataAccessLibrary.Models
@using Models

@inject IUserData _db

@rendermode InteractiveServer

<h3>Users</h3>

<h5>Insert new user</h5>

<EditForm FormName="Insert" Model=@newUser OnInvalidSubmit="@InsertUser">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />
    <div class="form-group">
        <InputText id="UserName" @bind-Value="newUser.UserName" class="form-control" /> <br />
        <InputText id="FullName" @bind-Value="newUser.FullName" class="form-control" /><br />
        <InputText id="Password" @bind-Value="newUser.Password" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
</EditForm>

@code
{
    private List<UserModel> user;
    public DisplayUserModel newUser = new DisplayUserModel();
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        user = await _db.GetUsers();
    }

    private async Task InsertUser()
    {
        UserModel us = new UserModel
            {
                UserName = newUser.UserName,
                Password = newUser.Password,
                FullName = newUser.FullName
            };

        await _db.InsertUsers(us);

        user.Add(us);
        newUser = new DisplayUserModel();
    }
}

Can you please help me....
I want to add new data to DB

The only caller to InsertUser() method from the form is for invalid submit.

replace
OnInvalidSubmit="@InsertUser"

with
OnValidSubmit="@InsertUser"

